# Foreach loop in Aspx page how to add checkbox and label

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

Foreach loop in Aspx page how to add checkbox and label values from datatable . Recieve all ticked checkbox value.

I have written this code in aspx page not in aspx.cs .

```
<% foreach (Employee myEmp in _empList)  {
       empName = myEmp.ToString();  %>

<div class="abc">
    <div class="pqr"> 
            <asp:Label Text="<% empName %>" runat="server"  ID="lblEmpName"></asp:Label></label> 
      </div>
    <div class="xyz">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox"  Checked="false" runat="server" />
    </div>                      
</div>
<%  }   %>
```

Comment: can you please make this a question and give us a hint what exactly you want to achieve, as well as tell us what you already did?

Comment: Who upvoted this poor question? Look [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on SO.

Comment: Do you want to create dynamic checkboxes as looping in your datas?

Comment: yes . Please see my updated que

Comment: One more question, do you have to do that in client side? If you don't do this in client side, you can do my what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: yes . I am using an object which is having n number of employes to display data. I wanted to get all the employee who are ticked in chkbox  on click

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just missing the `:` or `=` for the label. `<%` should be `<%:`. Use `:` to encode any html and avoid js injection.  More [info](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx/) on `=` vs `:`

```
<% foreach (Employee myEmp in _empList)  {
    empName = myEmp.ToString();  %>
    <div class="abc">
        <div class="pqr"> 
            <asp:Label Text="<%: empName %>" runat="server"  ID="lblEmpName"></asp:Label> 
        </div>
        <div class="xyz">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox"  Checked="false" runat="server" />
        </div>                      
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 List<user> userList = new List<user>();

        foreach (user usr in userList)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new CheckBox()
                                          {
                                              ID = "cb_"+usr.UserId,
                                              Text = usr.Name,
                                              });    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to add controls dynamically to asp.net page is oninit page-event.

you should try something like this.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        /*LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.ID = "lbAddFilter";
        pnlFilter.Controls.Add(lb);
        lb.Text = "Add Filter";
        lb.Click += new EventHandler(lbAddFilter_Click);*/

        // regenerate dynamically created controls
        foreach ( var employee in employeeList)
        {
            Label myLabel = new Label();
            // Set the label's Text and ID properties.
            myLabel.Text = "Label" + employee.Name.ToString();
            myLabel.ID = "Label" + employee.ID.ToString();

            CheckBox chkbx = new CheckBox();
            chkbx.ID = "CheckBox" + employee.ID.ToString();
            chkbx.Text =  "Label" + employee.Name.ToString();

            MyPanel.Controls.Add(myLabel);
             MyPanel.Controls.Add(chkbx); 
        }
    }
```